# Redefine class of superclass property

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, superclass, subclassing

Here is the **situation**:

I have Controller `A` and controllers `B`, `C` that are subclasses of `A`.

Next, i have classes `RLMObject` and `News`, `Events` that are subclasses of `RLMObject`.

In `A` i have a property `commonProperty`. And it presents in `B` and `C` like superclass's property.

**Question**: I need something like to tell to compilator, that depend of controller this is a property of custom class. For example, in `A` this is `id`, in `B` this is `News`, in `C` this is `Events`. Because in `A` i do common things with this property, like getting data and setting it in this property. And in `B`, `C`, i work with UI and need a concrete class of this property.

Maybe this is not clear description, and last example (about getting data) is a custom situation, but if somebody get through it, please share your experience.

Comment: If i guess correctly, you want to take same variable in parent and in child class for storing different value. If so I can suggest to override the same variable (but don't property synthesize) in child class, then when you use self.id, it will access parent class's attribute and only "id" will access to the child class. Let me know, if that works.

Comment: You shouldn't do this (I would say you can't do this, but Objective C is close enough to C that you can still lie about pointers) as you are violating the Liskov Substitution Principle. `commonProperty` should be typed according to the superclass of `News` and `Events` and you can use down casts in `B` and `C` to access this property as a subclass type

Comment: There is another better solution for this.